# XHR is not being logged when request is being made using fetchJson, NextJS

Tags: xmlhttprequest, next.js, cypress

We are using the NextJS framework in which a request is being made using 'fetchJson'. But, the issue is that the XHR request is not being logged by cypress.
Below is the logs displayed in the 'Network' - the address request is being made and it received 200. The logic in the programming is that when I enter Pincode that matches length 6, the fetchJson method is being called which makes the request.

Here is my code for my test case:

```
it("Validate Error message for PinCode ",function(){
cy.server({
method: "POST"
});
cy.route("POST","/api/address").as("mypin");

cy.get("form").within(()=>{
cy.get("[name='clientStreetNo']").type("Street");
cy.get("[name='clientStreetName']").type("StreetName");
cy.get("[name='clientArea']").type("are");
cy.get("[name='clientPinCode']").type("500082");
```

Here is a screenshot of test execution; it shows address request being made, in the network tab.

I have tried multiple ways to make cypress log the xhr request but it done;t log. How can i make the request log?